How to get a list of all sheet names that contain "week of" that updates on edit
Im new to Apps Script and need some assistance with the code required to get a list of all sheet names (current and those to be created) that will start with "Week of" in the title. Ideally this would update as new sheets are created (either on edit or on open)
The code below is what I have so far, but need it to filter the sheets and only show those starting with "week of" as well as have it update when new sheets are added
/**
 * Returns the names of all sheets.
 * 
 * @return The name of all sheets in the Google Sheets spreadsheet.
 * @customfunction
 */
function ALLSHEETNAMES() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheets = ss.getSheets();
  let sheetNames = [];
  sheets.forEach(function (sheet) {
    sheetNames.push(sheet.getName());
  });
  return sheetNames;
}

If found some code (see below) that will not count the first x number of sheets, but i'm not certain that this will remain the case as the document grows so would rather find something that will use the "week of" filter vs a set number of sheets to ignore.
function sheetNameArray() {
var out = new Array()
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i=6; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
return out 
}


Get the Value of 'Week Of'
Your Code is almost there, You just add a condition where you use toLowerCase() and includes() to get the desired output.

Script used:
 /**
 * Returns the names of all sheets containing 'week of'.
 * 
 * @return The name of all sheets all sheets containing 'week of' in the Google Sheets spreadsheet.
 * @customfunction
 */

function getAllWeekOfInSheetNames() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheets = ss.getSheets();
  let sheetNames = [];
  sheets.forEach(function (sheet) {
    if(sheet.getName().toLowerCase().includes('week of')){
      sheetNames.push(sheet.getName());
    }
  });
  return sheetNames;
}

Reference:

toLowerCase()
includes()


As far as I understood, you want to use this solution, but with .startsWith('Week of') instead of .includes(... .

Though it has some valid points, I think that the OP will have a definite pattern on their naming convention for the sheets and it shouldn't matter. Other thing on my mind when modifying the code was that the title stated contains 'week of'.

Thank you very much! this solved the week of problem. Is there something else I need to add to the code to ensure it updates when new sheets are added? Im fine with either an on edit or on open option. Would adding a trigger work or is it best to build it into the code?

@ShailenVadera  A custom function is recalculated when one of its parameters changes. See Refresh data retrieved by a custom function in Google Sheet

Lime Husky: Since the function doesn't return all sheet names, it might be nice to change the function name. Also, please note that the first snippet includes the JSDoc tag @customformula.

@Wicket, Thank you for the insights, I updated the code which is now matched in the function.

@LimeHusky, I'm sorry I made a mistake in my previous comment. The correct tag is @customfunction (I already removed @customformula from your answer).

Get the value of "Week of" | Not Case sensitive
I have different approach getting the value of Week of. 
It's not case sensitive whether you wanted to get the value of "Week Of", "WEEk OF" ,"week of" or etc

I used regex
here's the code:
function ALLSHEETNAMES() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheets = ss.getSheets();
  let sheetNames = [];
  sheets.forEach( sheet => {
    sheetNames.push(sheet.getName());
  });
  
  const regex = /\bweek\s+of\b/i;
  const matchedSheets = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < sheetNames.length; i++){
    if(regex.test(sheetNames[i])){
      matchedSheets.push(sheetNames[i]);
    }
  }

  return matchedSheets;

}

Reference:

REGEX
FOREACH


To get the sheetNames starting with "Week of":
let sheetNames = sheets.filter((sheet)=> sheet.startsWith('Week of'))

